# Appending new data to the Backbone Relational Relation

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model, backbone-relational

I'm trying to design a load more type of system where every time you press load more you add data to the existing collection. This is a rough sketch of how the UI looks.

Everything works pretty great except as you would except everytime I re-run the

```
items.fetch
```

---

**What it does:** It overrides the entire collection with the new data

**What I want it to do:** I want the new records returned to be added to the records collection not override old 'records'

How can I make this work so that the newly fetched records are appended to existing records and not overridden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `{ remove: false }` to your `fetch` call:

```
items.fetch({ remove: false, data: { nextId: this.info.get('nextId') } });
```

---

What's happening here is `Collection#fetch` will synchronize its models with the data the server returns. That includes adding new models, updating models already present, and removing models that are not included in the response.

> The behavior of fetch can be customized by using the available [set](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set) options. For example, to fetch a collection, getting an "add" event for every new model, and a "change" event for every changed existing model, without removing anything: collection.fetch({remove: false})

The available `set` options are `add`, `remove`, and `merge`. Setting one (or all) to `false` will disable that functionality in the `fetch`.

It sounds like you just want `{ remove: false }`, leaving the `add` and `merge` functionality.

Comment: oh wow that will be amazing if it actually works for the backbone relations automatically I will try this thank you. I'm assuming this would work perfect if I was doing the fetch directly on the collection itself. Here the fetch will be on the parent relational model which has the collection as a relation.

Comment: This is magical ... it works, although I really don't understand how since the collection is not on the actual object where i call fetch on but on a relation of itself! This is nice ty

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with [backbone-relational](/questions/tagged/backbone-relational),

But with a normal collection, you can do the following in parse method:

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
  parse: function(response){
    // you can update the info here like this.info = response.info or similar
    return _.union(this.toJSON(), response.records);
  }
});
```

Basically we combine the response with existing data and return it so that we maintain the previous data when the collection updates